# Windgo ebike charging problems

Tags: power, battery

Hi I've been asked to try and repair a friends Windgo ebike problem is with the battery/power it's a new bike yet is not turning on.
Also the battery shows the illuminated Red light always and doesn't turn to green.
Leading me to think that it is the 1st place to start my checking.
But would really appreciate your help and advice on this subject please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it’s a new bike you will be better to take or send back for repair, anything you do to either the motor or battery will certainly invalidate any warranty.

Comment: As a side note certain batteries can take an absolute age to fully charge from flat, are you leaving it on charge long enough ?

Comment: It's a friend who's asked me to look at it. So I'm looking for any tips etc but I'll try charging for a longer period just incase.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's fundamentally about electronic circuits related to motors and lithium batteries and not really about bicycles.

Comment: @AndyP According to https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1403/24228 this is not definitely off-topic

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I wasn't aware of that meta question (I don't check meta that often).  And according to the most upvoted answer (from Criggie) this falls under 'grey area'.  In this case, it really is purely an electronics question.  And finally, there is at least one other valid reason (not enough information) to vote close for this question.

Comment: @AndyP it’s definitely gray area, but I’m inclined to leave it open as it’s electronics intrinsic to an a commercially offered ebike (rather than someone’s self-built ebike project).

Comment: Its brand new and under warranty?  Don't do anything except contact the supplier, and if they can't fix it take it back.   Otherwise your friend might end up with a non-electric bike and no warranty, and you might end up without the friend.